# Google Docs API - Update linked tables

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to update tables in Google Documents with the new API. Tables are linked from a Google Sheet.

I tried the API explorer in google cloud. I am able to extract the document in json format and then filter out the tables. But within the table json structure, I do not find anything that I can update, I do not find anything that links the table to a spreadsheet. It is plain text (from the cells in the spreadsheet).

Here I am sharing one table from the json, with 2 rows and 1 column with "Written English" and "Verbal English" as cell value.

```
        "table": {
        "rows": 2,
        "columns": 1,
        "tableRows": [
        {
        "startIndex": 77,
        "endIndex": 95,
        "tableCells": [
            {
            "startIndex": 78,
            "endIndex": 95,
            "content": [
            {
            "startIndex": 79,
            "endIndex": 95,
            "paragraph": {
                "elements": [
                {
                "startIndex": 79,
                "endIndex": 94,
                "textRun": {
                "content": "Written English",
                "textStyle": {
                    "underline": true,
                    "foregroundColor": {
                    "color": {
                    "rgbColor": {
                    "red": 0.06666667,
                    "green": 0.33333334,
                    "blue": 0.8
                    }
                    }
                    },
                    "fontSize": {
                    "magnitude": 24,
                    "unit": "PT"
                    },
                    "weightedFontFamily": {
                    "fontFamily": "Arial",
                    "weight": 400
                    }
                }
                }
                },
                {
                "startIndex": 94,
                "endIndex": 95,
                "textRun": {
                "content": "\n",
                "textStyle": {
                    "foregroundColor": {
                    "color": {
                    "rgbColor": {
                    "red": 0.8784314,
                    "green": 0.16078432,
                    "blue": 0.42352942
                    }
                    }
                    },
                    "fontSize": {
                    "magnitude": 24,
                    "unit": "PT"
                    },
                    "weightedFontFamily": {
                    "fontFamily": "Arial",
                    "weight": 400
                    }
                }
                }
                }
                ],
                "paragraphStyle": {
                "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
                "lineSpacing": 115,
                "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
                "spacingMode": "COLLAPSE_LISTS",
                "spaceAbove": {
                "unit": "PT"
                },
                "avoidWidowAndOrphan": false
                }
            }
            }
            ],
            "tableCellStyle": {
            "rowSpan": 1,
            "columnSpan": 1,
            "backgroundColor": {
            "color": {
                "rgbColor": {
                "red": 1,
                "green": 1,
                "blue": 1
                }
            }
            },
            "borderLeft": {
            "color": {
                "color": {
                "rgbColor": {
                "red": 1,
                "green": 1,
                "blue": 1
                }
                }
            },
            "width": {
                "magnitude": 0.75,
                "unit": "PT"
            },
            "dashStyle": "SOLID"
            },
            "borderRight": {
            "color": {
                "color": {
                "rgbColor": {
                "red": 1,
                "green": 1,
                "blue": 1
                }
                }
            },
            "width": {
                "magnitude": 0.75,
                "unit": "PT"
            },
            "dashStyle": "SOLID"
            },
            "borderTop": {
            "color": {
                "color": {
                "rgbColor": {
                "red": 1,
                "green": 1,
                "blue": 1
                }
                }
            },
            "width": {
                "magnitude": 0.75,
                "unit": "PT"
            },
            "dashStyle": "SOLID"
            },
            "borderBottom": {
            "color": {
                "color": {
                "rgbColor": {
                "red": 1,
                "green": 1,
                "blue": 1
                }
                }
            },
            "width": {
                "magnitude": 0.75,
                "unit": "PT"
            },
            "dashStyle": "SOLID"
            },
            "paddingLeft": {
            "magnitude": 2,
            "unit": "PT"
            },
            "paddingRight": {
            "magnitude": 2,
            "unit": "PT"
            },
            "paddingTop": {
            "magnitude": 2,
            "unit": "PT"
            },
            "paddingBottom": {
            "magnitude": 2,
            "unit": "PT"
            },
            "contentAlignment": "BOTTOM"
            }
            }
        ],
        "tableRowStyle": {
            "minRowHeight": {
            "magnitude": 15,
            "unit": "PT"
            }
        }
        },
        {
        "startIndex": 95,
        "endIndex": 112,
        "tableCells": [
            {
            "startIndex": 96,
            "endIndex": 112,
            "content": [
            {
            "startIndex": 97,
            "endIndex": 112,
            "paragraph": {
                "elements": [
                {
                "startIndex": 97,
                "endIndex": 111,
                "textRun": {
                "content": "Verbal English",
                "textStyle": {
                    "underline": true,
                    "foregroundColor": {
                    "color": {
                    "rgbColor": {
                    "red": 0.06666667,
                    "green": 0.33333334,
                    "blue": 0.8
                    }
                    }
                    },
                    "fontSize": {
                    "magnitude": 14,
                    "unit": "PT"
                    },
                    "weightedFontFamily": {
                    "fontFamily": "Raleway",
                    "weight": 400
                    }
                }
                }
                },
                {
                "startIndex": 111,
                "endIndex": 112,
                "textRun": {
                "content": "\n",
                "textStyle": {
                    "foregroundColor": {
                    "color": {
                    "rgbColor": {
                    "red": 0.8784314,
                    "green": 0.16078432,
                    "blue": 0.42352942
                    }
                    }
                    },
                    "fontSize": {
                    "magnitude": 14,
                    "unit": "PT"
                    },
                    "weightedFontFamily": {
                    "fontFamily": "Arial",
                    "weight": 400
                    }
                }
                }
                }
                ],
                "paragraphStyle": {
                "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
                "lineSpacing": 115,
                "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
                "spacingMode": "COLLAPSE_LISTS",
                "spaceAbove": {
                "unit": "PT"
                },
                "avoidWidowAndOrphan": false
                }
            }
            }
            ],
            "tableCellStyle": {
            "rowSpan": 1,
            "columnSpan": 1,
            "backgroundColor": {
            },
            "borderLeft": {
            "color": {
                "color": {
                "rgbColor": {
                "red": 1,
                "green": 1,
                "blue": 1
                }
                }
            },
            "width": {
                "magnitude": 0.75,
                "unit": "PT"
            },
            "dashStyle": "SOLID"
            },
            "borderRight": {
            "color": {
                "color": {
                "rgbColor": {
                "red": 1,
                "green": 1,
                "blue": 1
                }
                }
            },
            "width": {
                "magnitude": 0.75,
                "unit": "PT"
            },
            "dashStyle": "SOLID"
            },
            "borderTop": {
            "color": {
                "color": {
                "rgbColor": {
                "red": 1,
                "green": 1,
                "blue": 1
                }
                }
            },
            "width": {
                "magnitude": 0.75,
                "unit": "PT"
            },
            "dashStyle": "SOLID"
            },
            "borderBottom": {
            "color": {
                "color": {
                "rgbColor": {
                "red": 1,
                "green": 1,
                "blue": 1
                }
                }
            },
            "width": {
                "magnitude": 0.75,
                "unit": "PT"
            },
            "dashStyle": "SOLID"
            },
            "paddingLeft": {
            "magnitude": 2,
            "unit": "PT"
            },
            "paddingRight": {
            "magnitude": 2,
            "unit": "PT"
            },
            "paddingTop": {
            "magnitude": 2,
            "unit": "PT"
            },
            "paddingBottom": {
            "magnitude": 2,
            "unit": "PT"
            },
            "contentAlignment": "BOTTOM"
            }
            }
        ],
        "tableRowStyle": {
            "minRowHeight": {
            "magnitude": 15,
            "unit": "PT"
            }
        }
        }
        ],
        "tableStyle": {
        "tableColumnProperties": [
        {
            "widthType": "FIXED_WIDTH",
            "width": {
            "magnitude": 363,
            "unit": "PT"
            }
        }
        ]
        }
        }
```

In short, I am trying to programmatically do what "UPDATE" button does on a linked table in Google Docs.

Looking forward to any help.
Thanks.

Comment: About ``I am trying to programmatically do what "UPDATE" button does on a linked table in Google Docs.``, unfortunately, in the current stage, it cannot achieve it using Document services and Docs API, yet. I expect that this situation will be resolved in the future update.

Comment: just making sure, the "new" google docs api, does not provide this functionality?

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, in the current stage, it cannot achieve it using Docs API, yet

Comment: thank you so much. I read nearly the complete documentation and have reached the same conclusion.

Comment: If such method was added to Document services and Docs API in the future, I would like to report here.

Comment: I have reported the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124793822

Answer (score 2):

The issue is created [here in the issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124793822). Star(on the top left) the issue to help Google priorotize the issue!