# Programmatically updating linked tables and charts in a Google Doc with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a template Google Doc with linked tables and charts that I need to programmatically update so that I can export it as PDF and send by email. I haven't found a way to do that neither with apps script nor google docs api. And I really want to avoid updating the template with static content.

I know [this question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772429/google-docs-api-update-linked-tables), but never has a positive solution been found.

If this is still not possible, maybe there is a work around? Like a chrome extension you can trigger that can simulate manual update? Or whatever. Doesn't have to be elegant or anything, just has to work somehow.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: this for example, I haven't kept the others
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772429/google-docs-api-update-linked-tables

Comment: The workaround would probably be remove the link and programmatically create/recreate the table from Google sheets.

Comment: That's my last resort, yes, I was hoping for a more time-efficient approach