# Google Docs - Automatically Update Linked Objects From Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Google Docs document with a few tables linked from a Google Spreadsheet.

When I click on Tools > Linked objects, it allows me to link all the tables in one click:
[image: Google Docs Linked Objects]

I was trying to find a script that automatically updates all the linked objects whenever someone tries to download the doc (using the direct URL to download a doc as a PDF).

Namely, I am trying to programmatically do what "UPDATE ALL" button does on a linked table in Google Docs.

Looking forward to any help. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Docs API - Update linked tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772429/google-docs-api-update-linked-tables)

Comment: not really, I tried but it doesn't do what I need

Comment: what does it do and not do?

Comment: The problem simply wasn't solved - " unfortunately, in the current stage, it cannot achieve it using Document services and Docs API, yet. I expect that this situation will be resolved in the future update"

Comment: I want this to occur automatically: 
https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2019/05/bulk-update-docs-slides.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it using:
https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#RefreshSheetsChartRequest

An example:

```py
def slides_get_service(oauth_client=None):
  ## Auth Setup
  service = discovery.build('slides', 'v1', credentials=oauth_client)
  return service 

def refresh_chart():
  slides = slides_get_slides_by_presentation_id(presentation_id=presentation_id)
  service = slides_get_service()
  for i, slide in enumerate(slides):
    p_elements = service.presentations().pages().get(presentationId=presentation_id, pageObjectId=slide.get('objectId')).execute().get('pageElements')[0]
    if p_elements.get('sheetsChart'):
      reqs = [{'refreshSheetsChart':{'objectId':p_elements.get('objectId')}},]
      rsp = service.presentations().batchUpdate(body={'requests': reqs}, presentationId=_PRESENTATION_ID).execute().get('replies')
```

Two key things to note:

1. In here I assumed that there is only one object(chart) on a slide. If there are more charts or other elements, then you can enumerate over p_elements instead of just using the first element.
2. If you want to be more efficient then you send a single request with the object ids representing all the linked charts as:

```py
reqs = [{'refreshSheetsChart':{'objectId':'chart1_id'}},{'refreshSheetsChart':{'objectId':'chart2_id'}},]
```